# Upload image to nodejs server using retrofit android, file undefined

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit, multipartform-data

I am using Nodejs server and Android for image uploading.

Node js code

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, '../uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log('file ',file);
        cb(null, (Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)));
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype == 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file // return undefined
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
    error.httpStatusCode = 400
    return next(error)
  }
  res.send(file)
})
```

Android code

```
File file = new File(compressedImagePath);
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
Call<ImageUploadResponse> call = service.uploadImage(filePart);
```

This returns in undefined in the server in the following code line.

```
const file = req.file
```

Is there any issue on both sides? This works perfectly in the postman.

Comment: First check the file size before uploading the image, if the file size is fine then check the for okhttp gzip interceptor while making the api call.